# How can i share to facebook app? Not to m.facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

This is the facebook share button that i use on my mobile version website.

```
<a class="fbs" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent('http://website.com'),'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436');return false;">Share on Facebook</a>
```

The problem is when i click him, i'm taken to the m.facebook.com page where i'm asked to log in, but i'm logged on my facebook application.
Are there ways to share through the facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to check out [AppLinks](http://applinks.org/documentation/) for this solution which allows you to link to a screen within a mobile application. You would need to pass the content you want to share into the Android intent, iOS would have different wording but should still be the same. Unfortunately I don't have experience with AppLinks as it's still fairly new but this should still be a good starting point.

**Old Answer**

The issue is you are using the web sharing instead of Android. Facebook offers an SDK for Android and more info can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Just a snippet from the documentation which may be relevant to you, this would allow to you share the developer page for Facebook.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
        .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

I encourage you read the resource I provided though as this should solve your problem. If you still have issues feel free to share with what you've done, and what is still confusing.